# django max folders number per user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I was thinking "Enterprise" :)
In my Django 1.5 project if I will reach the maximum ext4 number of folders

ext3: 31998* and
ext4: 64000

And as far as I know with 63.999 folders there are problems, let's say it's an academic value and it's better not have such amount.

E.g. users data folder.
Normally, I would solve like this

/data/users/id_user_1, /data/users/id_user_2, /data/users/id_user_N
and

```
user_data_path = settings.DATA_PATH + user.pk
```

With more than 40.000 users the above file system structure will collapse.

What will it be a best practices/approach for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is to partition the keyspace using simple integer division. Assuming that `partition_size` is your allowed maximum for a given directory, you can use:

```
os.path.join(settings.DATA_PATH, str(user.pk // partition_size), str(user.pk))
```

Example with `partition_size=200`:

```
>>> fn(101)
'\\data\\users\\0\\101'
>>> fn(201)
'\\data\\users\\1\\201'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create sub-directories for multi-level structure to hold more directories.

Simplistically, something like this assuming 40K is the limit.

```
/data/users/0/        # for 1 <= pk <= 400000
             /1
             /400000
/data/users/1/        # for 400001 <= pk <= 800000
             /400001
             /800000
....
```

You can design for as many levels as you want and how to create/use the levels.

Comment: Right! I saw other examples creating the folder structure based on md5: http://serverfault.com/questions/46384/how-to-solve-linux-subdirectories-number-limit, but for my purpose yours is the best! Thanks!

Comment: @Daviddd, set you can choose whatever strategy to create multiple levels, but key is you have to have multiple levels.